# IBM MQ dmpmqlog Not Generating Log with Persistent Data

Tags: ibm-mq

I want to use the `dmpmqlog` utility to view messages found in circular logs. Even though I follow everything as per IBM documentation, after I create the dump I'm unable to find the data in the logs. I stop the queue manager before running the `dmpmqlog` command, manually add few messages to the queue. But in the dumped log files these messages are not shown.

I used the following invocation of `dmpmqlog`:

```
dmpmqlog -m QMA
```

```
AMQ7701I: DMPMQLOG command is starting.
LOG FILE HEADER
***************

counter1  . . . : 56        
FormatVersion . : 5                    StrucId . . . . : 'HLFH'
logactive . . . : 3                    loginactive . . : 2         
logsize . . . . : 4096       pages
baselsn . . . . : <0:0:0:0>                
nextlsn . . . . : <0:0:16:43833>           
lowtranlsn  . . : <0:0:16:43129>           
minbufflsn  . . : <0:0:16:42697>           
headlsn . . . . : <0:0:16:42697>           
taillsn . . . . : <0:0:16:43832>           
hflag1  . . . . : 1         
               -> CONSISTENT
               -> CIRCULAR
HeadExtentID  . : 0                    LastEID . . . . : 1650643508
LogId . . . . . : 1650643508
FirstArchNum  . : 4294967295           LastArchNum . . : 4294967295
nextArcFile . . : 4294967295
FileCount . . . : 3         
Files . . . . . : 0, 1, 2
LastCId . . . . : 0                    softmax . . . . : 16777216  
LogPageSize . . : 4096      
RecOffset . . . : 4096      
MinAlign  . . . : 4096      
counter2  . . . : 56        


AMQ7719I: DMPMQLOG command is using a default of '0:0:16:42697' for the starting dump location.
LOG RECORD - LSN <0:0:16:42697>           
**********

HLG Header: lrecsize 212, version 1, rmid 0, eyecatcher HLRH
Creation Time: 2022-04-22 22:39:27.137 (UNKNOWN) (UTC +330)

LogRecdType . . : ALM Start Checkpoint (1025)
Eyecatcher  . . : ALRH                 Version . . . . : 1
LogRecdLen  . . : 192                  LogRecdOwnr . . : 1024   (ALM)
XTranid . . . . : TranType: NULL
ObjectName  . . : NULL
Qid . . . . . . : {NULL_QID}
ThisLSN . . . . : <0:0:0:0>                
PrevLSN . . . . : <0:0:15:50639>           

No data for Start Checkpoint Record


LOG RECORD - LSN <0:0:16:42909>           
**********

HLG Header: lrecsize 220, version 1, rmid 0, eyecatcher HLRH
Creation Time: 2022-04-22 22:39:27.137 (UNKNOWN) (UTC +330)

LogRecdType . . : ATM Transaction Table (773)
Eyecatcher  . . : ALRH                 Version . . . . : 1
LogRecdLen  . . : 200                  LogRecdOwnr . . : 768    (ATM)
XTranid . . . . : TranType: NULL
ObjectName  . . : NULL
Qid . . . . . . : {NULL_QID}
ThisLSN . . . . : <0:0:0:0>                
PrevLSN . . . . : <0:0:0:0>
```

Also my `CURRLOG` is showing no log files.

```
DIS QMSTATUS CURRLOG
     1 : DIS QMSTATUS CURRLOG
AMQ8705I: Display Queue Manager Status Details.
   QMNAME(QMD)                             STATUS(RUNNING)
   CURRLOG( )
```

What am I doing wrong here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

IBM MQ V 9.1

Comment: Are your messages persistent?

Comment: Please update your question with the complete invocation of the `dmpmqlog` command you used.

Comment: Hi Morag, yes my messages are persistent and am invoking dmpmqlog -m QMA, where QMA is my queue manager. I'm trying to simulate data GET and PUT using MQ Explorer, is that a concern, can that be a reason for data not shown in the dmpmqlog output. Thnx.

Comment: I have updated your question with the information about the `dmpmqlog` invocation and I have updated my answer with a recommendation to use the `-b` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you might have more luck with the `dmpmqlog` program if you try the following invocation:-

```
dmpmqlog -m QMA -b
```

The CURRLOG parameter is only applicable if you are using linear logging. Since you are using circular logging, it is expected to see a blank in there.

From IBM Docs about [DISPLAY QMSTATUS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=reference-display-qmstatus-display-queue-manager-status-multiplatforms):-

> **CURRLOG**
>
> The name of the log extent being written to at the time that the **DISPLAY QMSTATUS** command is processed. If the queue manager is using circular logging, and this parameter is explicitly requested, a blank string is displayed.

Comment: This worked Morag, may thanks as usual.